# Jupyter notebook kernel issue

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm having problems with the Jupyter notebook kernel, it appears connected with Python 3, but when I write a line of code it doesn't take the language, it seems that I'm writing as a markdown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written is in python 3 only. The * denotes that the particular cell is still running and the execution has not been completed yet.

Since you are downloading a dataset its taking some time which can be long depending on your internet speed.

Comment: I have a reasonable connection, but I can leave all day that nothing happens

Comment: Exactly when I run the line the kernel connection fails

Comment: install scikit-learn and reinstall sklearn just in case. See if they are the latest versions and try again. Let m know in comments.

Comment: unfortunately the problem stands

Comment: i don't know how to proceed w/ this problem

Comment: hi..just to identify whether the source of the problem is sklearn or this particular dataset you can run from sklearn import datasets and then iris = datasets.load_iris() separately in different cells...plz post the finding in the comments.